# Why does magento need to load all labels from universe to build color swatches?

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches, color-swatches

I'm working on a store that has 23k of possible color values.
But, they are not used on every product of course.

Now, that we are working on 1.9.2.1, that has native swatches, I see that the produt page tooks 3 minutes to load.

It's because *_loadOptionLabels* method of *Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Super_Collection*, that loads all of 23k colors each time a single product page is loaded.

Does anyone experienced the same problem, or have a guess of how to optimize it?

I also tried to [clean all unused option values](https://gist.github.com/zdravkok/d34ae4607950e4931a64), but still take so many time to load and using Resource_Iterator to speed up foreach, but didn't work. The problem is the big query.

Comment: I can't answer 'why', but we ran into this as well on a site with some 2k color options. Catalog views were taking a minute or more on account of the color swatches. We ended up disabling the module entirely on account of its unoptimized state, and rolled a custom solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a module to override \Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Super_Collection::_loadOptionLabels with the following:

```
protected function _loadOptionLabels()
{
    if ($this->count()) {

        $attributeIds = array();
        $productId = false;
        $filterLabels = false;
        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $attributeIds[] = $item->getAttributeId();
            $id = $item->getProductId();
            $productId[$id] = $id;
        }
        if (is_array($productId) && $attributeIds) {
            $filterLabels = true;
        }

        if ($filterLabels) {
            $productIntTable = 'catalog_product_entity_int';
            $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
                ->from(array('l' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')), array('i.value'))
                ->join(
                    array('i' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($productIntTable)),
                    'i.entity_id = l.product_id'
                )
                ->where('l.parent_id IN (?)', array_keys($productId))
                ->where('i.attribute_id IN (?)', $attributeIds);
            $optionIdsToSelect = $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($select);
        }


        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(
                array('attr' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_attribute')),
                array(
                    'product_super_attribute_id' => 'attr.product_super_attribute_id',
                )
            )
            ->join(
                array('opt' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option')),
                'opt.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id',
                array(
                    'attribute_id' => 'opt.attribute_id',
                    'option_id' => 'opt.option_id',
                )
            )
            ->join(
                array('lab' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option_value')),
                'lab.option_id = opt.option_id',
                array(
                    'label' => 'lab.value',
                    'store_id' => 'lab.store_id',
                )
            )
            ->where('attr.product_super_attribute_id IN (?)', array_keys($this->_items));

        if ($filterLabels) {
            $select->where('opt.option_id IN (?)', $optionIdsToSelect);
        }
        $result = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
            $select,
            array(function($args){
                $data = $args['row'];
                $item = $this->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id']);
                if (!is_array($labels = $item->getOptionLabels())) {
                    $labels = array();
                }
                $labels[$data['option_id']][$data['store_id']] = $data['label'];
                $item->setOptionLabels($labels);
            })
        );

    }
    return $this;
}
```

I've filtered the query, and replaced foreach with iterator.

It nows brings me about 24 to 40 records per product, instead 23.000. :)

This module also makes unnecessary calls on product listing when you dont have setup to show anything in product list. Maybe a rewrite of *Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Observer::productListCollectionLoadAfter* is required to check if configswatches/general/product_list_attribute has some attribute to load.